# How to send verification email after signup for auto-confirmed accounts with Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I want to send Amazon-Cognito verification email to "not email verified" but "confirmed" accounts.

I need to allow temporary access to my site for users with Email Verified = false. So I'm auto-confirming their accounts with the pre-sign up lambda trigger. Doing this "Email verified" keeps equal to false but the verification email is never sent.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I am stuck on this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a post sign up lambda which sends an email to the user with a URL. The URL has username of the user and triggers a lambda which will use [AdminUpdateUserAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) to set email verified to true.

You can use API gateway here to set up and endpoint to trigger your lambda.